# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'companyname' with Django in docker container

Tags: python, django, docker

I am getting an error about my module named "companyname" (fake name as to not reveal this project) despite the fact that it is in the folder with my Dockerfile.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libffi-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    net-tools \
    vim
COPY * ./
RUN pip install -U pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system
EXPOSE 8000
STOPSIGNAL SIGINT
ENTRYPOINT ["python3.7", "manage.py"]
CMD ["runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Here is my manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "companyname.settings.dev")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

And then there is a file that is located `./companyname/settings/dev.py` from my Dockerfile - so ostensibly it should exist in my Docker image from the copy command.

However when I run:

```
docker run <image hash>
```

I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'companyname'
```

Why can't manage.py find my module? The same directory structure should be observed, correct?

Comment: use `COPY . .` and add a step to list what do you have in docker `RUN ls -la`

Comment: Oh, it seems to be copying everything without the directories.

Comment: so then, you know what to do :)

Comment: Yep, changing * to . seemed to work and kept my directory structure

Answer (score 1):

`COPY * ./` does not keep directory structure, whereas `COPY . ./` does